# How to compile Xamarin Forms from source and use the assemblies?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I downloaded a copy of the current Xamarin Forms master branch, compiled it, and then I added these compiled assemblies as references to a test project:

- Xamarin.Forms.Core
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
- Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

The test project was created using the Visual Studio Xamarin Forms project template, the only thing I modified is the references in the Core.csproj and Android.csproj to point to the compiled assemblies.

I used the first 3 from the bin\debug\ folder of the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android project, and the last one from the Xamarin.Forms.Xaml bin\debug folder.

I run the test project, and it runs fine, I can see the label from the default generated code "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"

Next, I just modified the MainPage like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage());
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it gives me an error

> System.ArgumentException: element is not of type Xamarin.Forms.View
>
> Parameter name: element

thrown on this line:

```
        void IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement(VisualElement element)
        {
            if (!(element is TElement))
                throw new ArgumentException("element is not of type " + typeof(TElement), nameof(element));

            SetElement((TElement)element);
        }
```

which is strange.

The type of the element is `Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage` and the stack trace is

[image]

Can someone help me running the test project with the compiled assemblies?

**UPDATE #1:**

The 2nd entry in the call stack shows that it's not able to get the registered renderer(`NavigationPageRenderer`) for the `NavigationPage` element and instead it's creating a default renderer(`DefaultRenderer`), which can't handle the type of element(`NavigationPage`) so it's throwing the exception I see.

So it appears that for `NavigationPage`, it doesn't find its renderer(`NavigationPageRenderer`) in the `Registrar`.

```
    public static IVisualElementRenderer CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
    {
        UpdateGlobalContext(element);

        IVisualElementRenderer renderer = Registrar.Registered.GetHandler<IVisualElementRenderer>(element.GetType()) ?? new DefaultRenderer();
        renderer.SetElement(element);

        return renderer;
    }
```

My feeling is there's a build step I'm not aware about when building Xamarin Forms.

Comment: What type is it then? What OS are you building on? Does the code work if you use Xamarin.Forms from NuGet?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I edited the question to answer your questions and more. Please see the diff.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and targetting the same Android version which the XAmarin Forms project template set (Android 4.0.3). I didn't change anything in the settings. The code works OK with Xamarin.Forms from Nuget.

Comment: I think I found the issue :) Yay

Comment: @JamesL I am encountering over 70 errors, mostly in the Platform.Android. Did you not encounter any such errors when building from source? If you did, can you explain how you solved them?

Comment: Can you update with your solution? I am having the same issue

Comment: @JamesSugrue I didn't have any compile errors. Make sure your environment like Xamarin release branch, Android SDK are up to date

Comment: No I don't have any either.It builds and runs fine, but I have the same problem as you in Update 1 with the exception on NavigationPage

Answer (score 0):

Its crashing as you are calling InitializeComponent on something which doesn't derive from a Forms.Page (i.e. ContentPage etc).

The application itself is not a Page, if you had a page, lets call it 'MyCustomPage' which has some Xaml behind the class would look something like this:

```
public partial class MyCustomPage : ContentPage
{
  public MyCustomPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent ();
    // Some other setup...
  }
}
```

Then in your App constructor you would call

```
MainPage = new MyCustomPage();
```

Since you are creating a blank content page from the root of your app, you do not need to call InitializeComponent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to reference

```
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android (Forwarders)
```

from your Android project.

Comment: Just ran into this problem myself and this is what fixed it.